# Factoring $qz^2+2pz+q$ via the quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I am factoring $qz^2+2pz+q$ via the quadratic equation. So I get $z=\frac{-2p\pm \sqrt{4p^2-4(q)(q)}}{2q}=\frac{-p\pm \sqrt{p^2-q^2}}{q}$
If the two roots are $z_1,z_2$ then I think that $qz^2+2pz+q=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$ but my instructor is saying that I should get $qz^2+2pz+q=q(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$. I feel really frustrated because I can't see why that would be. Why can't I just use the quadratic equation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quadratic equation for $z_1$ and $z_2$ but since the original polynomial is not [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) you need an extra factor $q$ to have the correct coefficient for $z^2$

$$\color{red}qz^2+2pz+q=\color{red}q(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$$

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new today. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: think about what your "just use the quadratic equation" argument would say if you tried it for $2x^2 - 2 = 0$ and $3x^2 - 3 = 0$. Then you should be able to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't I just say $2x^2-2=0$ gives that $x=\frac{\pm\sqrt{16}}{4}=\pm 1$? Then indeed $2(\pm 1)^2-2=0$?...I am sorry I am still not seeing it...

Comment: Oh wait.. Then I would get (x-1)(x+1) which isn't right...

Comment: How can I avoid making this mistake in the future?

Comment: very simple and good hint!

Comment: Don't "use equations" without thinking about context. The quadratic formula tells you the roots, hence the factors of the form $(x-r)$. The product of those factors will always have leading coefficient $1$.